# Using an invariant to determine boundary conditions in binary search

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search, invariants, loop-invariant

I am trying to solve [Arranging Coins](https://leetcode.com/problems/arranging-coins/) on LeetCode.com:

> You have a total of n coins that you want to form in a staircase shape, where every k-th row
> must have exactly k coins. Given n, find the total number of full staircase rows that can be formed. n is a non-negative integer and fits within the range of a 32-bit signed integer.  For n=5, the output is: 2.

Based on [the solution given](https://leetcode.com/problems/arranging-coins/solution/), we can reformulate the problem as:

> Find the maximum `k` such that `k*(k+1)/2<=N`

My invariant (inspired by [this](https://www.quora.com/What-are-common-mistakes-for-implementing-binary-search/answer/Egor-Suvorov) Quora answer):

> I have a interval from L to R such that `a[L]`<=`k*(k+1)/2<=N` and `a[R]`>`k*(k+1)/2<=N`. Then, after I check element M in between, I set either L or R to M, preserving the invariant.

But I am unsure if my invariant is correct:

1. I am unsure if this will give me the `maximum` value of k;
2. Should I continue the iteration `while(l<r)` or `while(l<=r)`?  `l` and `r` are the usual two pointers used for iteration;
3. After I calculate `mid` as `k*(k+1)/2`, should I use `l=mid+1` or `l=mid` (and likewise `r=mid-1` or `r=mid`)?

Thanks!

Comment: The formula is unreadable do you have a better quality version???

Comment: @YunfeiChen, edited it.  Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

You are making the problem way too complexed, logically all you need to do is this:

```
int number = n; //the number you are getting
int index = 0;
int iteration = 0;
while(index <= number){
    iteration++;
    index += iteration;
}
return iteration; //this will be the maximum complete level, the code is incomplete but this sounds like an assignment so good luck!!
```

For a more effiecient solution you can use Guass's formula for summing up numbers for example to sum up the numbers 1-100 you can do the following:
101*100/2 or (n+1)*n/2..
So if you are comfortable you can:

```
int number = n; //the number you are getting
double iteration = sqrt(number/2.0)*2;//remember to add the brackets 
                                      //inside.
if(iteration - Math.floor(iteration) >= 0.5)return iteration + 1;
else return iteration;
```

If there are any errors feel free to correct me...

Comment: This is `O(n)`. :)

Comment: Always go for the most readable and simplest solution, if you do not need pointers do not create one...

Comment: Besides, my question is more about the invariants - not how to solve the question per se.

Comment: You know the two while loops you have do not like much better than O(n)....

Comment: I got you a O(1) solution, I do not think you can do any better....